# Swift "Enum" base object

Tags: swift, cocoa, enums

If I want to add an extension to every object I can do the following:

```
extension AnyObject
{
     func myFunc() { ... }
}
```

Is there something similar where I can add a function to every Enum? In other words, what is the base "class" for every enum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, note that you cannot do an extension to `AnyObject` as above, as `AnyObject` is a protected protocol (to which all classes implicitly conform) rather than a type. See e.g.

- [Is there a way to add an extension to AnyObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974260/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-extension-to-anyobject)

Now, you could, however, extend any specific *type* as you show above, e.g., `extension Int { ... }`. However `enum` is not a type; rather a "container" of ordered raw representable values. So a more valid comparison could be *"If I want to add an extension to every class, by `extension class` ..."*, which is, naturally, trickier.

Now, all enumerations *with a `rawValue`* and an *initializer by `rawValue`* conforms to [protocol `RawRepresentable`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/RawRepresentable/), so you could extend this protocol for specific *types* of raw values:

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue == Int {
    var sqrt: Double {
        return pow(Double(rawValue),(1/2))
    }
}
```

And this extension property would be available to all enumerations that explicitly use the same raw value type, in this case, `Int`:

```
enum MyIntegerLiteralEnum : Int {
    case One = 1
    case Two
    case Three
    case Four
}

print(MyIntegerLiteralEnum.One.sqrt)
print(MyIntegerLiteralEnum.Two.sqrt)
print(MyIntegerLiteralEnum.Four.sqrt)

/* 1.0
   1.4142135623731
   2.0               */
```

As a disclaimer, note that this extension will be made available to all types that conforms to `RawRepresentable` with a `rawValue` of type `Int`, not only enum types. E.g.:

```
struct Foo : RawRepresentable {

    typealias RawValue = Int
    var bar : Int

    var rawValue: RawValue {
        get {
            return bar
        }
    }

    init(rawValue bar: Int) {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

var a = Foo(rawValue: 16)
print(a.sqrt) // 4.0
```

Comment: Not all `enum`s conform to `RawRepresentable`.

Comment: @RomanSausarnes I didn't know that, will check up, thanks for feedback!