# Is there a way to apply an extension to all UIKit classes?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out a way to write Swift equivalents to Kotlin's *apply* and *also* methods. I think I know how I'm going to implement it, but was wondering whether there is a shortcut to applying it to all or most of the main uikit classes.

Basically, I want something like:

```
extension ____ {
    func apply(() -> void) {

    }

    func also(() ->  void) {

    }x
}
```

to be available to all classes.

Comment: You could extend NSObject if that helps.
Or AnyObject, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31988258/1649241)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to all UIKit classes in one step, but you can simplify things a little by applying it to classes that others inherit from. For example if you add an extension to `UIResponder`, it gets inherited by a **lot** of other classes, including `UIView` and everything that inherits from that, plus `UIViewController` and all of its descendant classes. Really that's pretty much everything that shows on the screen. Beyond that, you can pick off classes like `UIImage` and `UIColor`, if they make sense.

Comment: NSObject is even higher

Comment: Why wouldn’t extending NSObject work? Can you explain? Thx

Comment: @impression7vx Yes but the question was about UIKit. Using `NSObject` will involve many, many classes that aren't in UIKit.

Comment: is there some source that I could refer to to see how everything is connected? There has to be something better than just going to every classes individually in the docs

Comment: Ok but he didn’t say “all or most of the main uikit classes but no others”.

Comment: @satoshiMotoMoto I don't know of one in Apple's docs, but if you Google "UIKit class hierarchy" you'll find some useful diagrams. For example: http://ios-funda.blogspot.com/2015/04/uikit-class-hierarchy.html

Comment: @matt True but it's always best to limit the effect of an extension to classes where you want it to apply, instead of letting it apply to all kinds of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Is there a way to apply it across all classes? Including ints, strings etc

Comment: I like my answer better. It’s more extendable. Pun intended

Comment: Extending `NSObject` is a bad idea unless there's some compelling reason to need the extension on pretty much everything on iOS. You hit all of Foundation, UIKit, and dozens of other frameworks in one shot. If you don't actually need all of that, you're polluting the global namespace with unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the extension to NSObject.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject

Not sure if it is every class, but somewhere to start.