# Create objects dynamically in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift, introspection

In Objective-C I had a category:

```
@implementation NSObject (Entity)
+ (instancetype)entity{
    Class cl = self.class;
    NSObject *obj = [[cl alloc] init];

    return obj;
}
@end
```

Let's assume there are classes A and B:

```
@interface A : NSObject
@end

@interface B : NSObject
@end
```

And then I can use static `entity` method to create objects like:

```
NSObject *o = [NSObject entity]; // type of NSObject
A *a = [A entity];               // type of A
B *b = [B entity];               // type of B
```

How can I write that category in Swift? I know it's possible to create an object by knowing the type like `let s = NSString.self; var str = s.init()`, but here I don't know the class, that should be something like `self.self` which has no sense and doesn't work for sure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30176009/730701) is at least similar to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the reason is that there is no base class in Swift. You can still do it by implementing your own base class or by subclassing `NSObject`.

```
class A : NSObject {}
class B : NSObject {}

extension NSObject {
    class func entity() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}

A.entity()
B.entity()

NSObject.entity()
```

Comment: Isn't "dynamicType" enough?

Comment: `dynamicType` will not allow you to create an universal category, which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 5):

```
let s = NSString.self;
var str = s.init();
```

If you need the class, it's just:

```
print(s) // "NSString"
```

s is of Type "NSString.Type" 
it 's represent the Object class;

If you need the class of an object I think that you are searching "dynamicType":

```
let object = "toto"
let t = object.dynamicType // String.Type

var newObject = t.init("toto");
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, the whole point is that Objective-C provides base class for all classes, while Swift does not.  `NSObject` in obj-C provides `alloc` and `init` methods, hence one can expect that a descendant from `NSObject` will either implement or inherit those methods, hence you can have the shortcut-category you mentioned in your question.

In Swift there are no base classes, therefore you can not know which class (or other type) provides which initialisers.  One way or another you will have to resort to specifying them for your purposes, and I think that protocols are the best way  to do so.

E.g. consider this:

```
protocol DefaultInstantiatable {
    init()
}

extension DefaultInstantiatable {
    static func entity() -> Self {
        return Self()
    }
}
```

If your types adopt `DefaultInstantiatable` protocol then you could use clauses like:

```
struct Foo: DefaultInstantiatable {
    init() { }
}

class Bar: DefaultInstantiatable {
    required init() { }
}

let foo = Foo.entity()  // Creates an instance of Foo structure
let bar = Bar.entity()  // Creates an instance of Bar object
```

Comment: I can't get `return Self()` to work. Xcode 7.3.1 gives a syntax error.

Comment: It should work.  There must be some reason why it errors in your case.  Please create a separate question for that.

Comment: Ahhhh! My bad! And I just learned something cool from you-- I hadn't seen that this was in the context of a *protocol* extension. I like that! I was just generically trying to `return Self()` in a method and that wasn't working.